# How to transform a table to a new table after aggregation

Tags: spotfire

if you have Tabel = Table in Spotfire 
you want to transform that that to new tabe with aggregation like this in R

I do not want to use R but I want to use Spotfire functions

aggregate(list(vals=Table$vals), by=list(IDP=Table$IDP, Year=Table$Year, Month=Table$Month,Cust=Table$Cust), FUN=sum)

aggregate(list(vals=Table$vals), by=list(IDP=Table$IDP, Year=Table$Year, Month=Table$Month,Cust=Table$Cust), FUN=sum)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to add a pivot table. Click File > Add Data Tables > Add, and then select the table you want to pivot. Near the bottom where it says transformations, click the drop down box, select Pivot and then click Add. You'll want to select all of the columns mentioned in the by parameter of the R code as row identifiers. Select vals for values, and it should default to sum as the aggregation method. You can also change the column naming pattern. Check out the sample at the bottom and click OK until you've closed out the Add Data Tables window.